# Combinatorics: Sitting Order Thought Process

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Let's say we have a group of 7 children and 13 adults (each one is unique and can be picked once), and 20 chairs(each one is unique and can be picked once).

Question 1)
How to find the number of ways the group can be seated, if at least one adult must be seated between two children?

Question 2)
How to find the number of ways the group can be seated, if the children all sit next to each other?

Question 3)
How to find the number of ways the children can sit, if none of the adults sits?

Now, to answer Question 1, i thought of this: If A is an adult and C is a child, we can have either the pattern ACA, the pattern CAA or the pattern AAC.

So, we have $C_3(20) = \frac{20!}{(20-3)!} = \frac{20!}{17!} = 20\cdot19\cdot18 = 6840$  ways for each pattern, so in total we got $6840 \cdot 3 = 20520$ combinations.

To answer Question 2, i thought of this: the children can sit in $ P_7 = 7!$ different ways, and the adults can sit in $P_{13} = 13!$ different ways, so we got a total of $P_7 + P_{13} = 7! + 13!$ different ways in which they can sit.

To answer Question 3, i thought of this: we have $C_7(20) = \frac{20!}{(20-7)!} = \frac{20!}{13!}$ different ways the children can sit.

Am I getting this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2, you should multiply the $7!$ and $13!$ because for each order the children sit in you have $13!$ orders that the adults can sit in.  You also have to multiply by $14$ for the leftmost seat occupied by a child because sitting the children in seats $1-7$ is different from sitting them in seats $3-9$

For 3, your answer is the number of ways to choose the $7$ seats the children sit in, but does not account for the assignment of children to seats.  You should multiply by $7!$

For 1, we have to find the number of ways to choose seats for the children, then multiply by $7!$ and $13!$ as in 2.  It is easier to imagine a $21^{st}$ seat filled by an adult.  Then we can attach an $A$ to the right of each $C$ and have $14$ things to put in $14$ seats.  $7$ of them are $A$s and $7$ of them are pairs of $CA$.  We can choose seats for the $CA$s in $14 \choose 7$ ways.

Comment: Thank you for the response. For q3, why multiply by 71 specifically?

Comment: That was a typo.  It should have been $7!$ for the orders of the children.  Fixed

Comment: Oh I see.  Thanks again

Comment: I have another question for 2, if the chairs where in a circle, would the number of possible orders be $7!\cdot13!\cdot(\frac{13!}{7!\cdot6!})$ ?

Comment: No, it would just be $7!\cdot 13!$ because you can always rotate the table so the most clockwise child is in seat $1$.